# Como finalizar processo 'chrome.exe' ao finalizar execução do script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Implementei um script utilizando selenium que acessa algumas páginas. O código está funcionando exatamente como esperado.

O meu problema está quando script termina sua execução que acontece de duas formas:

- Quando o usuário fecha o navegador (ChromeDriver)
- Quando o usuário fecha o prompt de comando ou interrompe o script (Ctrl+C)

Após o encerramento da execução, ***o processo 'chrome.exe' continua ativo***, fazendo com que arquivos continuem sendo usados e trancando os mesmos (não pode deletar/mover/renomear...).

[Descobri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory) que existem comandos para encerrar esses processos.

`browser.close()` irá fechar apenas a janela atual.

`browser.quit()` fecha todas as janelas abertas.

Mas preciso disparar esses métodos nos momentos certos, ter gatilhos que acionem somente quando o usuário finaliza a execução.

Qualquer outra ideia/solução é bem-vinda.

Comment: o processo continua aberto em ambos os casos? tanto com o usuário fechando a janela quanto fechando terminal?

Comment: @KarlZillner sim, a partir do momento que o webDriver é iniciado `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`, o processo continua aberto em ambos os casos.

Comment: A expection `except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):` pode te ajudar para o Ctrl + C. Utilize o próprio `browser.close()` e o `browser.quit()` para finalizar o processo.